# Assembling SOAP Header manually with Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, savon

I've been dealing with a "soap message header incorrect" error message when submiting a SOAP request using Savon.

I copy/pasted the exact same xml generated by Savon into SOAPUI and I don't get that error and I get the expected response.

So, since I'm tired of trying different things, I want to assemble my own header without Savon help on that.

What I want to do is something like:

```
soap.header = "<wbs:Session><wbs:SessionId></wbs:SessionId><wbs:SequenceNumber></wbs:SequenceNumber></wbs:Session>"
```

However I get this error from Savon:

> **can't convert Symbol into String**

Why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the header will only accept a Hash - from the savon.rb page:

```
Besides the body element, SOAP requests can also contain a header with
additional information. Savon sees this header as just another Hash following
the same conventions as the SOAP body Hash.

soap.header = { "SecretKey" => "secret" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its likely caused by the fact you havent set any values.

I was getting this error when I had a hash containing just one custom object on return, as it was trying to access parts of the hash that had automatically been removed. (it removed unnesscary layer of hash for me :@)